# как устроен модуль Tkinter (python)

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

озадачен вопросом как устроен встроенный в дистрибутив питона модуль tkinter. Инфы хоть по какой нибудь внутренней его части нигде попросту я не нашел. Вопрос первый: рисует контролы операционная система, а не OpenGl, верно? тогда следует второй вопрос, в исходниках модуля (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_tkinter.c) вроде как ясно что используется winAPI, а как быть с линуксом, где для иксов что используется? А где для макоси? Где то лежит отдельно сборка для иных винде осей или я смотрю куда то не туда?

Comment: @insolor спасибо! препроцессорную ifdef уже только позже заметил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tkinter использует [Tk](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk), который под каждой системой использует свой способ отображения элементов управления. Tkinter (Tk interface) - только "обертка" над Tk.
2. В программах на C/C++ есть возможность для разных платформ при помощи `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` (см. [Препроцессор Си](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A1%D0%B8)) включать или не включать в готовую программу какие-то блоки кода. По приведенной вами ссылке все обращения конкретно к WinAPI обернуты в блоки `#ifdef MS_WINDOWS`, при компиляции под другие системы эти блоки в бинарный файл не попадают.

Comment: а что на счет отрисовки контролов, их ОС сама рисует в Tk?

Comment: @Ljachowsky, контролы рисуются средствами ОС.